# Magento custom tab and admin controller acl

Tags: magento, controller, admin, acl

I have an issue with a custom controllers ACL for the admin backend.
Ive read, re-read, checked....and still cant find my issue. Dammit.

First, the code...the module itself is working...i have blocks, helpers, front end controllers...system->config tab/group data...all working fine. My issue is just relating to admincontroller acl...so ill just add the relevant code for that area for now.

My backend  tab is showing, but the urls (admin/mynewmodule/index, admin/mynewmodule/list) go to a 404 page.

config.xml, admin routers:

```
 <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <mynewmodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">
                        Mworkz_MyNewModule_Adminhtml
                    </mynewmodule >
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Adminhtml.xml, backend tab, and acl

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
 <menu>
    <mynewmodule module="mynewmodule " translate="title">
        <title>MyNewModule</title>
        <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
            <children>
                    <items module="mynewmodule " translate="title">
                        <title>Index Action</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/mynewmodule/</action>
                    </items>
                    <list module="mynewmodule " translate="title">
                        <title>List Action</title>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/mynewmodule/list/</action>
                    </list>
             </children>
    </mynewmodule >
</menu>

    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <mynewmodule translate="title">
                                            <title>MyNewModule</title>
                                    </mynewmodule>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                    <mynewmodule translate="title" module="mynewmodule">
                    <title>MyNewModule</title>
                        <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <items translate="title">
                                <title>Index Action</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            </items>
                            <list translate="title">
                                <title>List Action</title>
                                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            </list>
                        </children>
                    </mynewmodule>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mynewmodule>
                <file>mworkz/mynewmodule.xml</file>
            </mynewmodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>

 </config>
```

Admin controller

```
 class Mworkz_MyNewModule_Adminhtml_MyNewModuleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
 {

protected function _initAction() {

    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('extbuilderpro/items')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));

    return $this;
}   

public function indexAction() {

    $this->_initAction()
        ->renderLayout();
}

 public function listAction() {

    $this->_initAction()
        ->renderLayout();
}

 }
```

Comment: Ive also been clearing my 'session', and 'cache' dirs after testing changes.

Comment: `adminhtml/mynewmodule /` - from where spaces

Comment: Also...my front end controller route is:  /mynewmodule/index               
My backend route is:  /admin/mynewmodule/index
These cant/wont clash will they, given the admin prefix on the backend?

Comment: If you write your own extension, path must be `module_name/admin_html/list`. Download free magento extension, for example: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/news-by-commercelab-3436.html and look at `etc/config.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your own extension, path must be `module_name/admin_html/list`. Download free magento extension, for example: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/news-by-commercelab-3436.html and look at etc/config.xml.

So right code:

```
<menu>
    <modulename module="modulename" translate="title">
        <title>Module Name</title>
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        <children>
            <add translate="title" module="modulename">
                <title>Add New Item</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>modulename/adminhtml_news/new</action>
            </add>
            <items translate="title" module="modulename">
                <title>Items Manager</title>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <action>modulename/adminhtml_news/index</action>
            </items>
            <settings translate="title" module="modulename">
                <title>Settings</title>
                <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/modulename</action>
            </settings>
        </children>
    </clnews>
</menu>
```

Comment: "path must be `module_name/admin_html/list`" is not a correct statement (because of the word "must"). This *can* be the path, but it's up to configuration.

Comment: @benmarks is right. If the above answer is correct, it means the config has been changed. On the original question, the config use `before` argument for the routers. Looks like the original problem was caused by empty spaces between `<mynewmodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">
                        Mworkz_MyNewModule_Adminhtml
                    </mynewmodule >`. What do you think about it?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Where I can read more about it? (If my question is admitted in this topic).

Comment: @doktorgradus "Shaun UUDotCom" use this method: http://web-magician.blogspot.com/2009/04/secret-feature-of-magento-13-sharing.html so that the routers still use `adminhtml` not defining his own routers (in your answer it is `modulename`)

Comment: thanks, i had the 'use' tags in a previous bit of code...forgot to move across after tweaking/rewriting. Now i know why thats needed :)